# PsGetSID shows two usernames and one SID

Tags: windows, active-directory, sysinternals

We changed the logon name of a person in AD from 'name1' to 'name2'. We had problems with some sql boxes picking up the old 'name2' and using it to authenticate so in tracking down why I ran:

`psgetsid name1`

and

`psgetsid name2`

, both give me the same SID. How can one SID have two usernames attached? I have checked the 'Active Directory Users and Computers' mmc snap in and searched the domain for users, contacts or groups>> Name = 'name1' and then 'name2'. Sure enough I get a common result but 'name2' is nowhere to be found in the common result('name1' is the logon name listed for example and it's also in the email field).

Comment: If you have multiple domain controllers, it's possible that there were some issues with replication.

Comment: Even if two dcs were off it would mean I got one dc on one call to psgetsid and another dc on the other call to psgetsid, correct?

Comment: You didn't specify the SQL Server versions you're running or your domain levels either as that may be important detail. You should consider setting up AD security groups & tying those groups to the SQL Server security at the global level rather than explicit accounts if that's possible in your case and this may not be an issue. Sometimes SQL Server takes time to cache up AD SID level changes and sometimes you just need to delete and readd the account (global security level) or restart the SQL Server instance for it to get the new username tied to the SID. I know it sucks but it is what it is.